# Cannot call setState in callback

Tags: reactjs, onreadystatechange

I am new to React, so I know I might not be doing everything right.

I am trying to call setStatus inside of a callback for onreadystatechange but getting an error in the browser.  The code does an AJAX call to the server to see if a proposed username is already in the database.  Upon return the onreadystatechange is executed.  There I am trying to set the new error message for the username if it already exists.

Here is my state data:

```
const initialState = {
  firstname: "",
  lastname: "",
  username: "",
  password: "",
  email: "",
  firstnameError: "",
  lastnameError: "",
  usernameError: "",
  passwordError: "",
  emailError: ""
};

class SignUpForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = initialState;

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.checkUserName = this.checkUserName.bind(this);
    this.checkEmail = this.checkEmail.bind(this);
    this.validateForm = this.validateForm.bind(this);
  }
```

This is where I update state in a change handler for fields in the form:

```
handleChange(e) {
    let target = e.target;
    let value = target.value;
    let name = target.name;

    if (name === "username") {
      value = value.toUpperCase();
    }

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
```

This is the routine where I am getting an error in the browser.  The lines where the error occurs is marked with a comment on the line below.

```
checkUserName() {
    let usernameError = "";
    let element = "";
    let checkNameResponse = "";
    let checkNameMessage = "";
    let request = "";

    let url = "";
    let userName = "";
    let requestData = "";
    let checkNameResponseJSON = "";

    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (request == null) alert("Unable to create checkDBForUSerNameRequest");
    else {
      url = "/php/CheckUsername.php";
      userName = escape(document.getElementById("username").value);
      requestData = JSON.stringify({
        username: userName
      });

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
          checkNameResponseJSON = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
          checkNameResponse = checkNameResponseJSON.returncode;
          checkNameMessage = checkNameResponseJSON.message;

          element = document.getElementById("SignupIcon");
          element.className = "displayIcon";

          if (checkNameResponse === 0) {
            element = document.getElementById("SignupIconFile");
            element.src = "/images/YesButton.png";
            element.alt = "Available";
            this.setState({ usernameError: "" });
          } else {
            element = document.getElementById("SignupIconFile");
            element.src = "/images/NoButton.png";
            element.alt = "Not Available";
            usernameError = checkNameMessage;
            this.setState({ usernameError: usernameError });  // BROWSER ERROR
          }
        }
      };

      request.open("POST", url, true);
      request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      request.send(requestData);
    }
  }
```

This is the text from the browser error:

```
0: Object doesn't support property or method 'setState'
```

Any ideas why this happens or how to fix?

Comment: `request.onreadystatechange = () => {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you are using `request.onreadystatechange = function() {}` instead of `request.onreadystatechange = () => {}` or `request.onreadystatechange = function() {}.bind(this)`

When you use `function()`, the scope of `this` changes.

Remember that `function() {}` and `() => {}` are **not** the same.

but `function(){}.bind(this)` and `() => {}` are the same.

Comment: Thank you.  I added ".bind(this)" to the end of the function and verified that worked.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, but since you're using a compiler and likely babel, you should probably switch to using `() => {}` This is where the industry is heading. You don't see `.bind(this)` much anymore

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind the onreadystatechange function using .bind or arrow function since when the function is executed it needs to access the correct `this` value referring to the class context.

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // all logic here
 }.bind(this)
```

or

```
request.onreadystatechange = () => {
   //all logic here

}
```